# Node app works in local computer but crashes when deployed to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, webpack

I'm trying to get my todo application to work on Heroku. It works fine on my local computer. I've uploaded a few projects before on Heroku successfully, but they would normally be React applications using Express. This particular app doesn't use React or Express but does use Webpack. For this reason I was utilizing a tutorial since I wasn't used to Webpack. I don't know if Webpack is the reason why this isn't working.

Heroku logs:

```
2022-06-13T22:26:02.535522+00:00 app[web.1]: webpack 5.73.0 compiled successfully in 977 ms

2022-06-13T22:26:02.612115+00:00 app[web.1]: assets by path *.js 281 KiB

2022-06-13T22:26:02.612117+00:00 app[web.1]:   asset main.js 280 KiB [emitted] (name: main)

2022-06-13T22:26:02.612118+00:00 app[web.1]:   asset main.6032012614ad1503c780.hot-update.js 862 bytes [emitted] [immutable] [hmr] (name: main)

2022-06-13T22:26:02.612119+00:00 app[web.1]: asset index.html 2.21 KiB [emitted]

2022-06-13T22:26:02.612119+00:00 app[web.1]: asset main.6032012614ad1503c780.hot-update.json 28 bytes [emitted] [immutable] [hmr]

2022-06-13T22:26:02.612119+00:00 app[web.1]: Entrypoint main 281 KiB = main.js 280 KiB main.6032012614ad1503c780.hot-update.js 862 bytes

2022-06-13T22:26:02.612120+00:00 app[web.1]: cached modules 181 KiB [cached] 39 modules

2022-06-13T22:26:02.612120+00:00 app[web.1]: runtime modules 27.3 KiB 13 modules

2022-06-13T22:26:02.612120+00:00 app[web.1]: webpack 5.73.0 compiled successfully in 33 ms

2022-06-13T22:26:58.931915+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

2022-06-13T22:26:59.007211+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL

2022-06-13T22:26:59.143050+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137

2022-06-13T22:26:59.333126+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

2022-06-13T22:26:59.338445+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting

2022-06-13T22:27:01.822030+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`

2022-06-13T22:27:03.459689+00:00 app[web.1]: 

2022-06-13T22:27:03.459698+00:00 app[web.1]: > javascript-todo-app@1.0.0 start

2022-06-13T22:27:03.459699+00:00 app[web.1]: > webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.js --open

2022-06-13T22:27:03.459699+00:00 app[web.1]: 

2022-06-13T22:27:04.703480+00:00 app[web.1]: <i> [webpack-dev-server] Project is running at:

2022-06-13T22:27:04.703728+00:00 app[web.1]: <i> [webpack-dev-server] Loopback: http://localhost:8080/

2022-06-13T22:27:04.703755+00:00 app[web.1]: <i> [webpack-dev-server] On Your Network (IPv4): http://172.17.89.182:8080/

2022-06-13T22:27:04.707270+00:00 app[web.1]: <i> [webpack-dev-server] Content not from webpack is served from '/app/public' directory

2022-06-13T22:27:05.584822+00:00 app[web.1]: asset main.js 280 KiB [emitted] (name: main)

2022-06-13T22:27:05.584830+00:00 app[web.1]: asset index.html 2.21 KiB [emitted]

2022-06-13T22:27:05.584831+00:00 app[web.1]: runtime modules 27.3 KiB 13 modules

2022-06-13T22:27:05.584831+00:00 app[web.1]: modules by path ./node_modules/ 166 KiB

2022-06-13T22:27:05.584832+00:00 app[web.1]:   modules by path ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/ 53.5 KiB 12 modules

2022-06-13T22:27:05.584838+00:00 app[web.1]:   modules by path ./node_modules/style-loader/dist/runtime/*.js 5.75 KiB 6 modules

2022-06-13T22:27:05.584838+00:00 app[web.1]:   modules by path ./node_modules/webpack/hot/*.js 4.3 KiB 4 modules

2022-06-13T22:27:05.584839+00:00 app[web.1]:   modules by path ./node_modules/html-entities/lib/*.js 81.3 KiB 4 modules

2022-06-13T22:27:05.584839+00:00 app[web.1]:   modules by path ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/runtime/*.js 2.33 KiB 2 modules

2022-06-13T22:27:05.584840+00:00 app[web.1]:   + 2 modules

2022-06-13T22:27:05.584840+00:00 app[web.1]: modules by path ./src/ 12.3 KiB

2022-06-13T22:27:05.584841+00:00 app[web.1]:   modules by path ./src/app/ 7.22 KiB 5 modules

2022-06-13T22:27:05.584841+00:00 app[web.1]:   modules by path ./src/*.css 5.04 KiB

2022-06-13T22:27:05.584841+00:00 app[web.1]:     ./src/main.css 2.24 KiB [built] [code generated]

2022-06-13T22:27:05.584842+00:00 app[web.1]:     ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!./src/main.css 2.8 KiB [built] [code generated]

2022-06-13T22:27:05.584842+00:00 app[web.1]:   ./src/index.js 58 bytes [built] [code generated]

2022-06-13T22:27:05.584842+00:00 app[web.1]: ./app.js 2.39 KiB [built] [code generated]

2022-06-13T22:27:05.584842+00:00 app[web.1]: webpack 5.73.0 compiled successfully in 918 ms

2022-06-13T22:27:06.030495+00:00 app[web.1]: assets by path *.js 281 KiB

2022-06-13T22:27:06.030507+00:00 app[web.1]:   asset main.js 280 KiB [emitted] (name: main)

2022-06-13T22:27:06.030507+00:00 app[web.1]:   asset main.6032012614ad1503c780.hot-update.js 862 bytes [emitted] [immutable] [hmr] (name: main)

2022-06-13T22:27:06.030508+00:00 app[web.1]: asset index.html 2.21 KiB [emitted]

2022-06-13T22:27:06.030509+00:00 app[web.1]: asset main.6032012614ad1503c780.hot-update.json 28 bytes [emitted] [immutable] [hmr]

2022-06-13T22:27:06.030509+00:00 app[web.1]: Entrypoint main 281 KiB = main.js 280 KiB main.6032012614ad1503c780.hot-update.js 862 bytes

2022-06-13T22:27:06.030510+00:00 app[web.1]: cached modules 181 KiB [cached] 39 modules

2022-06-13T22:27:06.030510+00:00 app[web.1]: runtime modules 27.3 KiB 13 modules

2022-06-13T22:27:06.030510+00:00 app[web.1]: webpack 5.73.0 compiled successfully in 401 ms

2022-06-13T22:27:52.336239+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/" host=js-todo-application.herokuapp.com request_id=a8cdba71-da2d-4eac-a82b-3bb096219680 fwd="70.123.87.243" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2022-06-13T22:28:02.361009+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

2022-06-13T22:28:02.388752+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL

2022-06-13T22:28:02.528575+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137

2022-06-13T22:28:02.591039+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

2022-06-13T22:28:03.163398+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=js-todo-application.herokuapp.com request_id=cfae3d23-ddae-4f84-96c2-ad606582de9e fwd="70.123.87.243" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "javascript-todo-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A Javascript app using webpack, objects, and localstorage",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.dev.js --open",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/tgoandrex/javascript-todo-app.git"
  },
  "author": "tgoandrex",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/tgoandrex/javascript-todo-app/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/tgoandrex/javascript-todo-app#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.73.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.9.2",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0"
  }
}
```

webpack.common.js:

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    plugins : [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./src/template.html"
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

webpack.dev.js:

```
const path = require("path");
const common = require("./webpack.common");
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");

module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: "development",
    output: {
        filename: "main.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
    }
});
```

webpack.prod.js:

```
const path = require("path");
const common = require("./webpack.common");
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");

module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: "production",
    output: {
        filename: "main.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist")
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, the root error seems to be this: `Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch`.  Can you add the code to your question where you start your server on the port that Heroku wants you to use?

Comment: You are referring to what Express normally configures for you correct? I don't have anything like that in this application. From what I kind of understand, Webpack is defining this for me with webpack-dev-server when I run 'npm start' and I get the result from http://localhost:8080/. Do I need to have Express installed and defined in like a server.js file just for Heroku?

Comment: Is this a web server?  If so, please show your code for the server.  If this is an automatically created webpack-dev-server for your static resources, then you need to go find the code it generated so you can look at it and post it in your question so we can see.  I would guess that it's not configured to start on the proper port for your Heroku installation.  I believe Heroku will set an environment variable that specifies what port your server must run on.  Your server HAS to use that port.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot find the code you are asking for. I believe the code simply doesn't exist here. I was however successful in uploading it to Netlify: https://spontaneous-sawine-8e2387.netlify.app/. In case you still want to see the entire code: https://github.com/tgoandrex/javascript-todo-app

Comment: Sorry, but I give up here.  Heroku is telling you that you aren't starting a server on the appropriate port.  Nothing more I can help you with.